# Azure ML Error: TimeSeriesImputer object has no attribute '_known_df'

Tags: time-series, azure-machine-learning-service, forecast

Running [this orange juice sales notebook](http://%20https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/forecasting-orange-juice-sales/auto-ml-forecasting-orange-juice-sales.ipynb) I get the below error with the `.forecast()` method.

#### code

```py
# The featurized data, aligned to y, will also be returned.
# This contains the assumptions that were made in the forecast
# and helps align the forecast to the original data
y_predictions, X_trans = fitted_model.forecast(X_test)
```

#### Error ([full stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/swanderz/201819978b6719bbed1826a02bb2fb47)):

```
**AttributeError: 'TimeSeriesImputer' object has no attribute '_known_df'**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is commonly fixed by upgrading to the latest SDK. You can do this by running `pip install --upgrade azureml-sdk[explain,automl]`.

Thanks,
Sabina

Comment: I tried updating to latest sdk 1.8, it didn't work, azml team has confirmed that it's a bug and has been fixed now. Thanks

Comment: Hi Deepak, Can you give me the name of the person from the Azure ML team who confirmed this was a bug? We fixed this bug a few months ago and a new fix for this is not on our radar. 

After upgrading can you ensure that you re-started the kernel to let the new SDK version take effect?

Thanks,
Sabina

Comment: Hi Sabina, Please find the issue discussion in the below link.Also, I did restart the kernel after the sdk update, I spent whole day thinking I am doing something wrong, now that issue is fixed but another issue with dnn I am facing, it's also mentioned in the same link below, thanks!

https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1030

Comment: also, compute vm images in azure are still using 1.7 version of sdk, usually how long does it take to get the updates in all the compute vm's in Azure? Are users expected to update it or it happens eventually?